# User input to chose an amount of letter and number from an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to learn C# and I am making a password generator. I have set an array with the letters and number I want the program to use.

```
String alphabet[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
```

I am trying to write a piece of code in a for loop that will pick random letters or numbers any amount of length that the user inputs.

Example for 
(y in alphabet (PwLength));

I just can't figure out how to get it to cycle through the loop choosing random letters.

Comment: Picking indices using System.Random, loop is to collect them to a System.Text.StringBuilder.

Comment: Unfortunately you are doing to have to dumb it down for me as I don't understand how

Comment: Someone did but I'd suggest to first try by yourself, usually SO questions should show an attempt or at least some understanding of the problem. For ready to use code there is...[careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use infinite random chars generator:

```
IEnumerable<char> GetRandomChars()
{
    string alphabet = 
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Random random = new Random();

    while (true)
        yield return alphabet[random.Next(alphabet.Length)];
}
```

Take first N random characters and create string:

```
var result =  new String(GetRandomChars().Take(length).ToArray());
```

Comment: You don't need `alphabet.Length - 1` since the bound is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Random here. The idea is to get the password length from user and set the allowed characters and then use Random to generate the password.

```
public static string CreatePassword(int passwordLength)
    {
        const string allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@$?_-";
        char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
            chars[i] = allowedChars[rd.Next(0, allowedChars.Length)];
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String password = "";
for(int i = 0; i < USERINPUTLENGTH; i++)
{
    //Get Random Char
    String randomChar = alphabet[Random.next(alphabet.length)];
    password += randomChar;
}
```

Comment: It would help if explain exactly how this code works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over the alphabet, but loop once for each character you want in the generated password.

```
string GeneratePassword(int pwLength)
{
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var random = new Random();

    for(var i = 0; i < pwLength; i += 1) {
        builder.Append(alphabet[random.Next(alphabet.Length)]);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```